# Does the equation $E=mc^2$ hold good for the non-fissionable materials also?

Tags: special-relativity, nuclear-physics, mass-energy

Though we know that the equation $E=mc^2$ holds good for the fissionable materials, I want to know whether this equation holds good for non-fissionable materials also or not?
I want to know whether anybody has bombarded the nuclei of any non-fissionable materials such as, say, gold or plain carbon also with neutrons and if so – how did the energy so generated compared with “mc^2”?
My question is – if this equation does not hold good for non-fissionable materials, should it not have been explicitly declared that it holds good for only fissionable materials?

Comment: Goto Wikipedia you can know it works for any thing known surround us. High school physics textbook may only say it work for fission process.

Comment: Heck, it holds for chemical reactions as well.

Comment: As for GiorgioP answer, certain processes, such a fission, are especially suited to see the mass energy equation at work, as for the energy involved is high enough to be seen as a mass defect. Opposite, but just for every practicall meaning, mass is conserved upon chemical reactions and other processes involving relatively small energies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it holds for non-fissionable materials. For example, it holds for a proton, or an electron, or a hydrogen atom. It would hold even if fission did not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the equation $E=mc^2$ is often related to nuclear reactions is purely historical. The possibility of this kind of  application was already suggested by Einstein himself at the end of his 1905 paper where he derived the equation. The first successful application of the formula is considered the first estimate of the Uranium fission energy by [Lise Meitner  and Otto Frisch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Robert_Frisch).

However, Einstein's derivation, based on the analysis of the absorption of a plane wave of light by a  body and how this process may affect its inertia, is completely general and holds without exceptions. 
Therefore it is valid for chemical reactions, although in that case the relevant energies are small with respect to the masses of reagents and products. It holds also for any variation of energy, even if not connected to the presence of bound states.

Answer (score 0):

This equation's mass $E=mc^2$ is not the mass used in nuclear and particle physics, because it is not a mass invariant to Lorentz transformations, it is a function of  velocity.

It holds for all matter, from elementary particles to space ships, and it gives the *inertial mass* of the system at that velocity. Its only real use is to decide how much fuel to take on a spaceship that will fly at  a small fraction of the velocity of light.

What is Lorentz transformation invariant is the [invariant mass](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) , the "length" of the four vector, for particles and systems of particles, as the nuclei are.

[image: invm]

> The length of this 4-vector is the rest energy of the particle. The invariance is associated with the fact that the rest mass is the same in any inertial frame of reference.

So for systems at rest the relativistic mass and the invariant mass coincide, as in the nuclear physics experiments and in the binding energy curve the mass of the nuclei by weight is used for $m$ because these experiments are done at rest.

> anybody has bombarded the nuclei of any non-fissionable materials such as, say, gold or plain carbon also with neutrons

A lot of experiments have been done, if you look at the literature, but whether energy will come out after the scatter is a matter of the [binding energy curve,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Nuclear_binding_energy_curve), which defines whether energy is needed or will be given out depending on the particles used.

> My question is – if this equation does not hold good for non-fissionable materials, should it not have been explicitly declared that it holds good for only fissionable materials?

There is no reason to speak of the reativistic mass in nuclear experiments, that is why there is no decaration. It is the rest mass that is important.